# Scala - What is type Input and what are Input.Source and Input.Offset mean?

Tags: scala

I read this question:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815716/accessing-scala-parser-regular-expression-match-data)

And this is a block of code its accepted answer:

```
/** A parser that matches a regex string */
  implicit def regex(r: Regex): Parser[String] = new Parser[String] {
    def apply(in: Input) = {
      val source = in.source
      val offset = in.offset
      val start = handleWhiteSpace(source, offset)
      (r findPrefixMatchOf (source.subSequence(start, source.length))) match {
        case Some(matched) =>
          Success(source.subSequence(start, start + matched.end).toString, 
                  in.drop(start + matched.end - offset))
        case None =>
          Failure("string matching regex `"+r+"' expected but `"+in.first+"' found", in.drop(start - offset))
      }
    }
  }
```

I dont understand some parts of the code:

- The code between curly braces is like it is defining a new class although before it is "new Parser[String]" which I knew is create a new instant of class Parser[String]
- In the code, there is a function apply take a parameter of type Input, but I didnt found any class like it on Scaladoc and its members: source, offset

Can you explain those parts to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Input` is a type alias in [Parsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.2/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers) from the [scala-parser-combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) library.

At the time that answer was written, parser combinators were still in the [scala standard library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers). They have been removed as of Scala 2.11.

The doc for `Parsers` (and also for `RegexParsers`, which I'd guess is more specifically what's being used here) says `type Input = Reader[Elem]`, so `Reader` is the type that has `source` and `offset` fields.

`new Parser { ... }` defines an anonymous class that extends `Parser[String]`.

Comment: Im sorry. What is it alias to in this case since Im sure that Regex have no member Source and Offset? And what about the first part, how can we define that curly braces and the apply method after "new" something? About the version, I still use 2.9.2 so It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It says in the doc: type Input = Reader[Elem]. Reader has source and offset fields.

Comment: The `new` with curly braces defines an anonymous class that extends Parser[String].

Comment: Didnt know about anonymous class before. I will accept your answer but it would be good if you copy the comment onto the main answer for easier access.